# Django rating model with m2m

Tags: python, django

I'm confused with my django models,
My models:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/", default="photos/none/default.png")
    film = models.ManyToManyField(Film)

class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEARS)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default="images/none/blank_poster.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and now I trying to make a ratings for my film, when user adding a film to his list.
I tried M2M with through, but it wasn't exactly what I wanted, because user could add the same film several times and another problem with it was remove single film from list.
Now i thinking about additional models like this:

```py
class FilmRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film)
    rate = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

Im glad If you can point me to the correct way to solve this problem, In future I want probably to store all rating from users for set average rate.

Comment: The second approach is much cleaner and you should go on with this.

Comment: I will tested it tomorrow, thank you for response.